# Pharmaceutical firm data

Tags: data-request

I have a query regarding pharmaceutical data. As part of my Ph.D. in Health Economics, I am interested in research questions such as the impact of mergers, competition, etc. on the pharmaceutical industry or firm innovation let's say.

Could you please suggest to me where I can access firm-specific pharmaceutical data to address the above type of research questions?

Answer (score 1):

[Quandl](https://www.quandl.com) has some free data on the pharmaceutical industry... Do you think the data from the following databases might help you get started?

- Federal Reserve Economic Data:

https://www.quandl.com/data/FRED?keyword=pharmaceutical

- United Nations Industrial Development Organization:

https://www.quandl.com/data/UIST?keyword=pharmaceutical

- United Nations Commodity Trade:

https://www.quandl.com/data/UCOM?keyword=pharmaceutical

- Central Bank of Brazil Statistical Database:

https://www.quandl.com/data/BCB?keyword=pharmaceutical

To see what else Quandl has, you can go to https://www.quandl.com/search and search for "pharmaceutical". You will also see data for pharmaceutical companies/stocks etc.

[Disclosure: I work for Quandl]

Answer (score 1):

[Enigma](http://enigma.io/) has a number of datasets related to the health space, and pharmaceutical companies in general, such as datasets released by the Food and Drug Administration, the National Institutes of Health and the Centers for Disease Control and Prevention, among other agencies.

The data is free for non-commercial use. In particular you might check out the NIH's [Clinical Trials](https://app.enigma.io/search/source/us.gov.nih.clinical-trials) data as a benchmark for firm innovation.

[Disclosure: I work for Enigma :) ]